# How to install react animated slider

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, npm-install, react-navigation-v5, react-animated

How did we install react animated slider for React version 16 plus+, as i'm installing it gives me error that it will be install only for react version 16 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgVbC.png)

Comment: it could be deprecated or it's name has changed

Comment: looks like it works - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-animated-slider-fully-animated-forked-q69n3l.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.